# Did I upload a document to Chromium by mistake?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, imac

I am working on an iMac, and when I right-click to choose a program to open a document, Chromium by Chrome is now listed as an option. I clicked it by mistake and wondered if I uploaded a private document to this program? I am a bit freaked out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot upload a document to a program.
Uploading means that you send a document to a website. That is hard to do by accident.

The reason "Chromium by Chrome" is now in the "Open With" menu is that it has registered itself as a program that can open the type of document you tried to open. This sometimes happens during the installation of the program.

There is no harm done.

Comment: Thank you so much! I had never seen it before, and I got scared! :)